# Effectively highlighting column and row on a DataGridView as mouse moves

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, datagridview

I am trying to highlight the row and column which the mouse is on. Essentially this means to change the background color of all the appropriate cells. Currently I am trying to do this in the MouseMove event. However, this is causing slow performance.

I was suggested to use WPF for better performance, however I do not wish to go that route. What are some ways in which I can improve performance within C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `CellMouseEnter` event; it fires only once each time the mouse moves over a new cell, unlike `MouseMove`, and it doesn't require clicking on the cell to fire the event. You should probably handle the `CellMouseEnter` (for highlighting the new cell), `CellMouseLeave`(for un-highlighting the old cell) and possibly the `Leave` event of the entire DGV (to make sure all cells are unhighlighted).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DataGridView.RowEnter Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowenter.aspx) which occurs only when a new row becomes active. The msdn links shows exactly the same sample you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: But this is only for when the mouse is clicked on a new row. I need to track the mouse as it moves.